# Framing argument for insert cursor when writing geometries using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geometry, cursor

I am writing polygon geometries and I have points holding the geometries that represent vertices of the polygon.

When I run the code below I get:

> TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row

```
cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc_path, ["SHAPE@"])

# Stuff
    X_Min = DF_extent.XMin
    X_Max = DF_extent.XMax
    Y_Min = DF_extent.YMin
    Y_Max = DF_extent.YMax

    point_0 = arcpy.Point(X_Min, Y_Min)
    point_1 = arcpy.Point(X_Min, Y_Max)
    point_2 = arcpy.Point(X_Max, Y_Max)
    point_3 = arcpy.Point(X_Max, Y_Min)

   # this is the part that is causing errors:
    cur.insertRow((point_0, point_1, point_2, point_3, point_1))
```

When I have the vertices that make up a polygon, what is the correct way to pass that information to the insert cursor so it knows that all of those points are, in fact, one argument to be taken at once?

Comment: You have this tagged with 10.0, but are using DA cursors, which were released at 10.1.  Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact ArcGIS release.  Note that there's an [entire documentation topic on writing geometries](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/writing-geometries.htm) (and to avoid coordinate value corruption, the `SpatialReference` should always applied to `Geometry` constructors)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a polygon object, instead of a list of point objects.  You can create a polygon object from your point objects, and then pass that to your insert cursor.

See:  [Polygon class documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polygon.htm)